# Python str in str implementation/complexity

Tags: python, string, time-complexity

I'm currently working with some big text files (books).

does anyone know how python's "str in str" is implemented / time-complexity?

e.g:

```
'bc' in 'abcde'
```

I'm trying to find out the worst case and the avg. case

Thanks!

Comment: It is explained here http://effbot.org/zone/stringlib.htm

Comment: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/stringlib/fastsearch.h